# Probabilities involving functions of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have been looking for a resource to explain this and have had no luck. How does one prove the following statement: Let $u>0$, $X$ a random variable, and let $E(X)$ be the expected value of $X$. Then

$$
P(X>E(X)+t)=P(e^{uX}>e^{u(E(X)+t)}).
$$

I have been filling in the blanks of some details left out by the authors of a book I am reading. At first glance it seems like a reasonable statement, but I don't know where to begin and have not found any references in my other texts.

Comment: This is simply using the fact that the functions $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = ux$ are strictly increasing. Therefore, $X > E(x) + t$ if and only if $g(X) > g(E(x) + t)$ if and only if $f(g(x)) > f(g(E(x)+t))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that $X>E(X)+t$, and let $B$ be the event that $e^{uX}>e^{u(E(X)+t)}$.

But since $x \mapsto e^{ux}$ is an increasing function,
$X>E(X)+t \implies e^{uX}>e^{u(E(X)+t)}$
and therefore $A \subseteq B$.
Also, since $x \mapsto \frac1u\ln x$ is an increasing function,
$e^{uX}>e^{u(E(X)+t)} \implies X>E(X)+t$
and therefore $B \subseteq A$.

Therefore $A = B$ and $P(A) = P(B)$.

Comment: Thank you for the consise and clear answer.